# NodeJS / Mongoose Filter JSON

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am building a JSON API with ExpressJS, NodeJS and Mongoose:

Input -> id:

```
app.get('/folder/:id', function (req, res){
  return Cars.find({reference: req.params.id}, function (err, product) {
    if (!err) {
      console.log(product);
      return res.send(product);
    } else {
      return console.log(err);
    }
  });
});
```

It shows well the JSON:

```
[{"_id":"B443U433","date":"2014-08-12","reference":"azerty","file":"087601.png","
....:.
{"_id":"HGF6789","date":"2013-09-11","reference":"azerty","file":"5678.pnf","
...
```

I just want to **display the _id** in the JSON, so it is good when I have lots of data.

How I can do that? Something like a filter?

Comment: In the JSON I am building with the app.get() I just want to have _id in the response (not date or file for instance). I am using mongoose and mongodb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to iterate over your "products" object to obtain the ids

Something like this:
(Disclaimer: I haven't tested this)

```
  app.get('/folder/:id', function (req, res){
  return Cars.find({reference: req.params.id}, function (err, product) {
    if (!err) {
      console.log(product);

      var ids = new Array();
      for(var i = 0; i < product.length; i++){
          ids.push(product[i]._id);
      }
      return res.send(JSON.stringify(ids));
    } else {
      return console.log(err);
    }
  });
});
```

--Edit

Also, "products" may already be a JSON string.  You may want to parse it before looping.

```
product = JSON.parse(product);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can chain calls to [`select`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select) and [`lean`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) to retrieve just the fields you want from the docs you're querying:

```
app.get('/folder/:id', function (req, res){
  return Cars.find({reference: req.params.id}).select('_id').lean().exec(
    function (err, product) {
      if (!err) {
        console.log(product);
        return res.send(product);
      } else {
        return console.log(err);
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are true but I think it's better to limit data in mongoose like this :(it's same as mongo shell commands)

```
app.get('/folder/:id', function (req, res){
    Cars.find({reference: req.params.id} ,{ _id : true } ,function (err, product) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log(product);
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```